# "Not as silver" in Isa 48:10

Tags: isaiah

In Isa 48:10 God is saying how the people will be refined as in "the furnace of affliction" -

> Isa 48:10 - See, I have refined you, **but not as silver**; I have
> tested you in the furnace of affliction.

What is the implied allusion in the phrase, "but not as silver" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, how was Israel refined relatively near to Isaiah's time?  Israel had struggled with idolatry.  Both the Northern and Southern Kingdoms at times had monarchs caught up in idolatry.  After the Babylonian Captivity idolatry was essentially purged from Judah, and eventually even from the Samaritans.

> הִנֵּה צְרַפְתִּיךָ וְלֹא בְכָסֶף בְּחַרְתִּיךָ בְּכוּר עֹנִי׃
> (Isa. 48:10, MT/BHS)

The phrase "not as silver" is simple Hebrew, one that a beginning Hebrew student can read.  It means that Israel was refined, not in a literal fire as silver is refined but symbolically with the affliction of the Captivity.  Essentially, the land of Israel, both Northern and Southern Kingdoms were desolate after the Babylonian captivity.  Affluent civilization was in Babylon.  Those desiring idolatry stayed in Babylon.  Only those devoted to God went through the hardship of returning to the land of Israel.  After the Babylonian Captivity, idolatry was unheard of among Judah; thus, the Judah Jesus the Messiah came to.

> [10] See, I refined you, but not as silver—which is put through fire to eliminate the dross; cf. Isa 1:25: “And I will smelt out (ואצרף) your dross” (quoted above). For the prefixed preposition beth, meaning “as,” see Num 18:10: “You shall partake of them as most sacred donations (בַּקֹּדֶשׁ).” Some commentators suggest that כּוּר, “furnace,” in the next clause, is implied here as well, and thus translate: “See, I refined you, but not [in a furnace in which one refines] silver”; cf. Prov 17:3; 27:21: “For silver—the crucible; for gold the furnace.” The Akkadian etymological and semantic equivalent, ṣarāpu, also denotes the smelting of metals (CAD Ṣ:102), and the noun ṣarpu means “silver” (ibid., 113–14).
> --
> Paul, S. M. (2012). Isaiah 40–66: Translation and Commentary (p. 312). William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company.

Answer (score 0):

the  early modern English text says **with** instead of **as**

> 10 Behold, I have refined thee, but not with silver; I have chosen thee in the afurnace of baffliction.

usually **refining** in OT is related to purify or clean. Also, silver is the example of refining, because refining silver requires put it in a fair distance from the fire, if too close or for too long it will be ruined, on the other hand, if the opposite, it won't be refined.

Comment: Where does this text come from?  I was unaware that any old English translation existed exect for the Gospels and the heptateuch.

Comment: here is the [link](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/isa/48?lang=eng)

Comment: That is not Old English - it is early modern English

Comment: sorry about that, I'm not a native English speaker, Answer updated